# Difference between arrival and departure

Tags: python, dataframe, date, datetime, time

```
departure_day        departure_time            arrival_day        arrival_time  
1                    00:00:00                  3                  01:00:00   
1                    10:00:00                  1                  02:00:00   
6                    15:00:00                  1                  06:00:00
```

I would like to have a variable that has the difference between those two. 1 is for Monday and 7 for Sunday. Additionally, sometimes it goes from 6 to 1 for example like the last case.

I would like to convert it to hours and days in the end. 
So far I have transformed them also to DateTime variables but I am struggling at the moment. Any tips on how to move forward?

```
Example output:
difference (in hours)
49
14
39
```

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit? Provide an example of how you want the output to look like for a specific test case. It'd be nice if you could provide what exactly the "difference between arrival and departure" would look like for the 3rd case.

Comment: I essentially want to see the duration of the trip, I will now add an example output! Thank you

Comment: "So far I have transformed them also to DateTime variables but I am struggling at the moment." Can you show us the code you have at the moment, and explain what the problem with it is?

Comment: Without the date columns for both departure and arrival, it is impossible to infer duration from your dataframe. day 1 can be a Monday two month ago, or last year, or just two days ago. The total duration of your trip will be different depending on these dates.

Answer (score 0):

Please find below the code snippet for this:

```
def day(departure, arrival, dep_time, arr_time):
    if departure<=arrival and dep_time<arr_time:
        total_hours=abs(hours(dep_time,arr_time).hours)+ (arrival- 
        departure)*24
    elif dep_time>arr_time and departure==arrival-1:
        total_hours=24+(hours(dep_time,arr_time).hours)
    elif dep_time<arr_time and departure!=arrival-1:
        total_hours=abs(hours(dep_time,arr_time).hours)+ (7+arrival- 
        departure)*24
    elif dep_time>arr_time and departure!=arrival-1:
        total_hours=24+(hours(dep_time,arr_time).hours)+ (6+arrival- 
        departure)*24
    return total_hours

def hours(dep_time,arr_time):
    arr=datetime.strptime(arr_time, FMT)
    dep=datetime.strptime(dep_time, FMT)
    diff = relativedelta(arr, dep)
    return diff
```

Note: I think your second row is incorrect. Please check.